# How to add two apis in react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm newbie React and English :D
I have a question. Is it possible for one API to get to Header and a second API to an accessor?

if it is possible. How?

I tried something but I know is really wrong. Any Ideas?

**App.js**

I tried to use map() anything and I didn't know what can I do and How?

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [header, setHeader] = useState([]);

const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('something');
    const data = await response.json();
    setData(data);
}

const fetchHeader = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('anything');
    const data = await response.json();
    setHeader(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    fetchHeader();
}, []);


const headers = header.map(col => ({
    Header: col.ColumnName
}))


const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: headers,
            accessor: 'BusinessPartnerLogoUrl',
            Cell: (cell) => (
                <>
                    <img src={cell.row.original.BusinessPartnerLogoUrl} width={86} />
                </>
            )
        },
        {
            Header: 'Produkt',
            accessor: 'ProducText',
        }
    ],
    []
);

return (
    <>
        <div className="container">   
            <div className="row mt-2">
                <ActiveTable columns={columns} data={data}/> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </>
    );
}
```

Thi si second file

**ActiveTable.js**

```
return (
    <Box>
        <TitleTable color="#009FB5">Aktivní smlouvy</TitleTable>
        <Table {...getTableProps()}>
            <TableHead>
                {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                    <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => {
                            return <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
                            
                        })}
                        <th><FilterButton filterColumns={allColumns} /></th>
                    </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableHead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row, i) => {
                    prepareRow(row);
                    return (
                        <TableRow {...row.getRowProps()} className="b-left-table tablerow-hover">
                            {row.cells.map(cell => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
                            })}
                            <td><ActionButton/></td>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                })}
            </tbody>
        </Table>
        <LegendaTable/>
    </Box>
   
);
```